# If First name is empty in DE, then its should remove space between HI & variable

Tags: marketing-cloud

i want to remove white space if First name is empty in DE **Hi %%=Propercase(first_name)=%%,** if empty then it should look like **Hi,** if have First name in DE then it should look like **Hi abcd,**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [iif](https://ampscript.guide/iif/) function to achieve that:

```
%%=Iif(not Empty(first_name), concat("Hi ", Propercase(first_name), ","), "Hi,")=%%
```

Comment: @Shared solution working fine, Thanks a lot :)